# Directive definition syntax clarification

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If I declare the following isolate scope in a directive definition:

```
scope: {
    state: '=', 
},
```

Is it accurate to say the `=` links the `state` property on the isolate scope to the value of returned by the expression associated with an attribute named `state` on the directive declaration, run in the parent scope?

Comment: The documentation puts it this way:  _"localModel (=state) will reflect the value of parentModel (=state) on the parent scope"_. Parentheses added by me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example say your directive is like below,

```
<div ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <directive-name state="scope_variable"></directive-name>
</div>
```

then if we use like this

```
scope: {
    state: '=', 
},
```

`state` attribute on the directive should be a `$scope (testCtrl's)` variable, If its a scope variable then `state` is pointing to same variable in the `testCtrl`'s scope.

or a expression for ex like `...state="'scope_variable'"...` then it's a String and it's not pointing to a scope variable, and also if you defined it as `...state="1+2"...` then its a expression so that `state` variable inside directive scope is equals to `3`.

hope this make sense.

here is a [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/8SKIbi75zPYOfej6G8iV?p=preview).

**note**

if we define the directive as isolated scope `scope: {}` then angular will create a child scope from its immediate parent, *(parent scope of the previous example is `scope of testCtrl`)*.

see the console of the provided demo and see the `console.log(scope.$parent.name);` is pointing to the `$scope.name` of `MainCtrl`'s scope.

Comment: Yes, that makes, sense, but can you confirm that my description in the question is correct? Specifically that the expression is evaluated in the parent scope.

Comment: i update the answer, please check it. :), what they refering to `parent scope` is the scope of `testCtrl` in the example.

Comment: So, if my understanding of your answer is correct, then my statement in the question was correct?

Comment: I have added a simple demo